# NetworkX DiGraph Edges with a specific on a based on their initial node

Tags: python, csv, graph, nodes, networkx

I've a graph done with networkx to visualize the relationships from a CSV file with around 500 rows long. To improve the visualization I have tried to color specific edges.

- Ideally only coloring: (any to A), (any to B), (A to any), (B to any).
- There are around 140ish edges, so I can't color them manually.
- I've tried to loop through the graph.edges and create a list, as
  that's what the nx.draw expects to receive but it didn't work out.
- I've managed to color all edges in different colors, but I need to have specific colors, for only certain edges.

This is what I have now (simplified)
[image]

Color each edge from a different color
[image]

This is what I'd like to have
[image]

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot :)

**CSV:**

```
from;to
A;G
B;A
C;A
D;S
V;A
V;S
V;A
M;S
M;A
...
```

**graph.edges:**

```
[('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'F'),
```

**CODE:**

```
# Read the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=";")

# Create the directed graph
graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source="from", target="to", create_using=nx.DiGraph()) 

# Create dummy weight and assign a color
d=dict(graph.edges)
count=graph.number_of_edges()
print(count)
values = range(count)

# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(12,12), dpi=120)
pos = nx.shell_layout(graph, scale=8)
nx.draw(graph, pos=pos, node_size=600,node_color='lightblue', edge_color=edge_colors, linewidths=0.05, font_size=6,with_labels=True ) #font_weight='bold', ,
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
edge_colors = [0 for edge in graph.edges()]
edge_map = [
    ((0, 'A'), 1),
    ((0, 'B'), 2),
    ((1, 'A'), 3),
    ((1, 'B'), 4)
            ]

for idx, edge in enumerate(graph.edges()):
    for node, color in edge_map:
        if edge[node[0]] == node[1]:
            edge_colors[idx] = color

edge_colors
```

gives

```
[1, 3, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3]
```

which, when passed to your call of `nx.draw()`, plots:

[image]

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to change the colors using the `cmap` keyword argument of `nx.draw()` or changing the literal values in the `edge_map` list.